# Populating new field based on existing string field using ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, string

My programming is really rusty at this point, and I am trying to do a simple calculation using a Codeblock, either VB or Python is fine. I have tried about 50 different variations on same theme, and get a runtime error every time.

Here's a screenshot of my Field Calculator. Basically, Field !Items! contains a string of all items separated by a comma, and I am trying to create new fields that contain a "y" if that item is present in !Items!, in this case it's "Baby Items". It is always capitalized like so, no need to worry about case mismatch.

```
def calc (items)
  if items.find("Baby Items") != -1:
    return "y"

calc (!Items!)
```

[image: Field Calc Screencap]

Comment: Please include your code as text rather than a picture so that potential answered can copy/paste it for testing.

Comment: You could find all the rows containing 'Baby Items' using items like '%Baby Items%'  query and calculate baby = "y".. note the wildcard is different for data types, percent works for shapefiles and file geodatabases but for personal geodatabases use asterisk as the wildcard. see http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/building-a-query-expression.htm#GUID-EC06FE3F-38BA-4CF2-AEAF-F69D65C7C567 and search for LIKE. Note some data types have case sensitive SQL but some do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there.  Try this:

```
def calc(items):
    if "Baby Items" in items:
        return "y"
```

This will check for the string "Baby Items" contained in the field `items`.

Also remember the colon `:` after `def calc(items)` -> `def calc(items):`

Comment: Ahh, thanks, it was the colon after (items), I knew it was something ridiculous like that!!! I started using "in", and then kept re-inventing the wheel from there.

Comment: It won't let me upvote since I am a n00b here!